# Which method adds products to an order in the admin?

Tags: admin, php, javascript

I want to automatically add products to an order in the backend(!), when a certain quantity of products is reached.

I've been searching in the backend's JS files, but I have no idea which method (must be PHP?) adds the products to the quote when I create an order via the backend.

I'm kind of stuck in these two files:

- js/mage/adminhtml/sales.js
- js/mage/adminhtml/configure.js

Does anyone has an idea how these products are actually added? Which class/method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController::_processActionData()`.
That one handles most requests from the admin order create page.

Specially take a look at these lines.

```
/**
 * Adding products to quote from special grid
 */
if ($this->getRequest()->has('item') && !$this->getRequest()->getPost('update_items') && !($action == 'save')) {
    $items = $this->getRequest()->getPost('item');
    $items = $this->_processFiles($items);
    $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->addProducts($items);
}
```

This handles the post sent when you add items to the cart.

If you want to dig deeper you should inverstigate `$this->_getOrderCreateModel()->addProducts($items);`

`_getOrderCreateModel` returns `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')` so you can check the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create::addProducts()`.

Comment: Ah, it seemed I was already close to the answer.. I was already looking in the CreateController, but at the wrong methods.. I think I can figure the rest out for myself now!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create` model (this can be found in`app/code/core/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`).

Notice the session that Magento applies when creating an order via the backend (`__construct()`):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
}
```

You'll need to add the product (using it's entity id) to this quote object. You'll be using both a combination of PHP & JavaScript to detect this, simply broken down:

- **Javascript**: Detect quantity of products added to cart
- **PHP (via AJAX):** add product to quote object